# Choosing device filter in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

When choosing a device filter, I see the following options:

[image]

I'm not experienced in hardware and I would like some advice. What would happen if I choose one over the other?

Ideally, I would like my app to be as light as possible. But, it would be nice to see the pros and the cons of each filter.

From my testing, I saw that ARMv7 makes my APK the lightest possible. What would I actually loose if I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARMv7 is the most common processor between the Android devices nowadays. There´s a growing amount of devices now including x86 processors.

You can make 2 apps with one apk for each processor and upload them to the Play Store using the Multiple APK approach.

On the other hand you can compromise a bit the weight of your application and ship for both x86 and ARMv7 architectures with that FAT option.

Here you have some info about Multiple APK publishing:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

> By publishing your application with multiple APKs, you can:
>
> Support different OpenGL texture compression formats with each APK.
>
> Support different screen sizes and densities with each APK.
>
> Support different device feature sets with each APK.
>
> Support different platform versions with each APK.
>
> Support different CPU architectures with each APK (such as for ARM, x86, and MIPS, when your app uses the Android NDK).

Hope it helps.